# Flags if certain conditions are present for columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df

```
Key1   Key2   Condition   Value1   Value2
K1     K2        1          10       202
K1     K2        2          610      206
K1     K2        3          130      250
K11     K21      1          150      270
K11     K21      3          510      20
K13     K23      2          32        5
```

Now i need flags for all conditions 1,2,3 for all key value combinations

- For e.g. K1,K2 has all 3 conditions 1,2,3 and 3 rows, one corresponding to each condition. So flag for all conditions will be Yes
- Keys K11,K21 have only conditions 1 and 3, condition2 is missing. So flags for 1 and 3 will be yes.
- Keys K13,K23 have only condition 2, condition 1 and 3 are missing. Flag for condition2 will be yes.

**Expected output**

```
Key1   Key2    Condition1  Condition2   Condition3 
K1       K2       Yes        Yes         Yes     
K11     K21       Yes        No          Yes 
K13     K23       No         Yes         No
```

Comment: Looks like you should write some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) to test not missing values and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

`DataFrame` for boolean:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index=['Key1','Key2'], columns='Condition', aggfunc='size')
        .notna()
        .add_prefix('Condition'))
print (df)
Condition  Condition1  Condition2  Condition3
Key1 Key2                                    
K1   K2          True        True        True
K11  K21         True       False        True
K13  K23        False        True       False
```

If you need `yes, no` values, then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df, 'Yes','No'), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
Condition Condition1 Condition2 Condition3
Key1 Key2                                 
K1   K2          Yes        Yes        Yes
K11  K21         Yes         No        Yes
K13  K23          No        Yes         No
```

Last if you need `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Key1 Key2 Condition1 Condition2 Condition3
0   K1   K2        Yes        Yes        Yes
1  K11  K21        Yes         No        Yes
2  K13  K23         No        Yes         No
```